# What forms do I need to fill out for a super basic LLC closing?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company

I made the mistake of turning my photography business into an LLC last year. I was really not ready for it and now I would like to close it down and end my business.

I have no employees, I'm the sole owner or the busness, I don't owe any creditors or anyone any money at all (beside the IRS taxes on $4000 of income from this year), and I plan to keep my photography gear (I owned it all before I went into business).

The IRS has a boat load of forms and I'm just not sure what ones apply to me since I kept everything super basic. The "check list" of forms on theit site I "may" need to fill out, widley don't apply to me so I'm at a loss.

If anyone could help I would be greatly appreciative. With a new baby I'm trying to avoid spending money on a CPA if I can.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

If it is a sole proprietorship and  you didn't make another mistake by explicitly asking the IRS to treat it as a corporation - there are no IRS forms to fill.

You'll need to dissolve the LLC with your State, though, check the State's department of State/Corporations (depending on the State, the names of the departments dealing with business entities vary).

Comment: I registered last year with the IRS as an LLC, but I believe I told them I was a sole proprietorship type LLC. I had to pay the $800 payment to the IRS (I live in CA) for being an LLC so I would assume the are seeing me as a corporation?

Comment: @Lacy2 you haven't registered with the IRS and you didn't pay $800 to the IRS. You registered with the CA SOS and you paid to the CA FTB. You need to cancel the registration with the CA SOS. The IRS (the US Federal Government) has nothing to do whatsoever with your LLC (a California entity).

Comment: You're right! Geez, mommy vrain in full effect over here. I'm sending off the papers to dessolve my LLC with the SOS today. I wont need to send anything to the CA FTB then it sounds like?

Comment: I believe not, as long as you dissolve it with the SOS within a year of the last $800 due date (which is on the registration anniversary, not calendar years).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I really appriciate your help! I really can't  thank you enough! It's so good to not have this off my plate and now I can just focus on my family. You're the best! Thabk you again! =)

Comment: @littleadv do you need to close your account / cancel your EIN with the IRS? Link: https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/canceling-an-ein-closing-your-account