# When shutting down a single-member LLC do you need to close your business account with the IRS?

Tags: united-states, irs, limited-liability-company

I'm shutting down a single-member LLC and have filed the necessary paperwork with the city and state in which I live. The only thing remaining is what, if anything, do I need to file with the IRS. I saw this question:

> [What forms do I need to fill out for a super basic LLC closing?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/63026/what-forms-do-i-need-to-fill-out-for-a-super-basic-llc-closing)

and they mentioned there being no forms necessary to file with the IRS. While searching though, I came across this page:

> https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/canceling-an-ein-closing-your-account

that mentions that you can request that the IRS close your business account. The page states the EIN remains tied to your LLC forever, but the account itself can be closed. Is closing the business account with the IRS something that should, or needs to, be done?